# How to parse this JSON (or json looking thing) in PHP (tried everything)?

Tags: php, json

So I'm coding a website that gets a JSON array and I'm getting part of that which is this:

```
[{"1:3"=>37},{"3:F"=>84},{"4:16"=>1},{"3:A"=>2224)]
```

Now since I have the square brackets, that means an array, correct? So I'm doing ($content is the array above):

```
$content[0]
```

which should just get the first part of the array, which is

```
{"1.3"=>37}
```

and then from that, I just want to get the value of 1:3.
However this does not work, because when I try to get [0] of the original array, it returns "[" instead of what I want it to. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: this not a correct Json.

Comment: Try [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate something to see if it is JSON, but `=>` definitely isn't JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "[", it means that the data is a string and you are getting the first character. So, you need to parse the string as JSON, and then get the object you want from that.